# Getting just one value with 2 same text from datalist in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datalist, html-datalist

I' am trying get just the row with one value but i getting 2 values o more values with the same text(), because the requeriment is with the text().

code for edit:
https://codepen.io/Dragonbl4ck/pen/BarOdvQ

```js
$(document).on('change', '#dataListOption', function () {
$("#result").val($("#JobPositionsLst option[value='" + $('#dataListOption').val() + "']").text());
});
//Help me please i just want one ID
//if you select C-Suite you get 2 ID's together (AC1AC2)
//Expected result is: AC1 or AC2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="JobPositionsLst"  id="dataListOption" placeholder="Job...">
    <datalist id="JobPositionsLst">
        <option value="C-Suite">AC1</option>
        <option value="C-Suite">AC2</option>
        <option value="Coordinator">COR</option>
        <option value="Administrator">ADM</option>
        <option value="Manager">MAN1</option>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <hr>  
    <h5>The result is repeated with 2 id together:</h5>
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly>
```

I get data with:

```
    IdData = $("#JobPositionsLst option[value='" + $('#dataListOption').val() + "']").text();
```

let me show you the result:

```
console.log('IdData',IdData) 
IdData: AC1AC2
```

But i just get one value:

```
IdData: AC1 or  IdData: AC2
```

Thank you.

Comment: How is it supposed to know which one to use? Why do you have duplicate values in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar This is requirement for the project Sir.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. `<datalist>` isn't like `<select>`, there's no selected option. Remember that these are just suggested values, the user doesn't have to choose from the list. What's supposed to happen if the user types `C-Suite` by hand, there's no way to know which one he meant.

Answer (score 0):

just add aspace to any of the (C-Suite) values. it looks for element based on their values, were you have two.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#dataListOption', function () {
  $("#result").val($("#JobPositionsLst option[value='" + $('#dataListOption').val() + "']").text());
});
//Help me please i just want one ID
//if you select C-Suite you get 2 ID's together (AC1AC2)
//Expected result is: AC1 or AC2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="JobPositionsLst"  id="dataListOption" placeholder="Job...">
<datalist id="JobPositionsLst">
  <option value="C-Suite">AC1</option>
  <option value="C-Suite ">AC2</option>
  <option value="Coordinator">COR</option>
  <option value="Administrator">ADM</option>
  <option value="Manager">MAN1</option>
</datalist>
<br>
<hr>  
<h5>The result is repeated with 2 id together:</h5>
<input type="text" id="result" readonly>
```